# Basis for the Definition of a diagonal matrix.

Tags: matrices, soft-question

I found the definition of a square matrix on Wikipedia as [image: wikipedia screenshot]
Well my question is a very stupid one that why we  defined the diagonal matrix on the basis of a *main diagonal* rather than the anti diagonal (that is the other *diagonal* on the given square matrix)... I know that it is **defined** that way but still there must be a reason as to why it is defined only in this particular way(*on main diagonal*) as I don't think it is arbitrarily defined.

Comment: For example if you inverse diagonal matrix in the example above you will obtain another diagonal matrix with inverted values on diagonal. And in general it is easier to work with diagonal matrices rather than "anti diagonal".

Comment: The reason for the definition (as for most definitions) is that it is _useful_. Diagonal matrices (defined that way) come up all the time in linear algebra and its applications. Diagonal matrices (defined the other way) don't.

Comment: Multiply the unit matrix by a vector and compare to the anti-unit by a vector.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker I honestly find it rather strange that the main diagonal occur more often than the anti diagonal but still...since I am not a mathematician or something like that still I guess I have to accept this stark reality ....but I would really appreciate if you could give such an example which shows its usefulness.. And how it is observed in many places.

Comment: @Yves thanks for the help but i don't know multiplication of a matrix by a vector (yet)...

Comment: So basically it is defined that way because it is found in many places ...maybe I will get this when I study all this in very detail...so should I close the question now ?

Comment: You could accept @NikolasWojtalewicz 's answer now, then come back when you've studied linear algebra and provide your own new answer then.

Comment: If that can shed more light, the elements of the diagonal are $a_{i,i}$, while those of the antidiagonal are $a_{i,(n-i+1)}$, i.e. they relate different components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The motivation for this is the identity matrix. Multiplying any vector or matrix by the identity gives you back what you started with. The idea of defining a diagonal matrix is that its the next "nicest" type of object. Multiplying any matrix by a diagonal matrix leaves the original very similar to the original.

Here's an example for you to think about. Take any 3 x 3 matrix A. Multiply it by

$$ \bar{I} = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

How did A change? Compare it to what happens if you multiply A by the identity

$$ I = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: And this is because we structured the matrix product to work this way, which is in fact again defined arbitrarly.